# Python variable made out of with only uppercases

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, global-variables, python-3.9

I recently bought a book called "Black Hat Python". However, I found that some variables are only made out of uppercase and the book was using it like a global variable.
Is there any feature in python that globalize variable by making a variable with only upper cases?

Comment: This is just a convention, usually for **constants** (a fixed value not modified by the code), not always used . For example I sometimes use `MAX` when I need to store a max value not to conflict with the builtin `max`, which doesn't make it a global nor immutable variable ;)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078731/conventions-on-creating-constants-in-python

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no such method. Rather you could define a global variable using the `global` keyword.

Here is an example:

```py
def myfunction():
    global s
    s += ' Hello World'
    print(s)
    s = "I love python"
    print(s)
 
# Global Scope
s = "Python is great!"
f()
print(s)
```

You can refer to this link for reference - [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/)

Answer (score -1):

There is no any difference for python how you set your variable. Uppercase may be used just for visual explanation.

You can read more about it via link:

-> [Python variables](https://realpython.com/python-variables/#:%7E:text=Officially%2C%20variable%20names%20in%20Python,name%20cannot%20be%20a%20digit.)